# Lyrics command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was trying to make a lyrics command using the lyrics ovh api in discord.py and I'm getting this error : "An error occurred: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'lyrics'"

````py
import aiohttp

@commands.command()
    async def lyrics(self, ctx, artist,*, title):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
           async with session.get(f"https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/{artist}/{title}") as response:
                data = await response.json()
                lyrics = data['lyrics']
                if lyrics is None:
                    await ctx.send("Song not found! Please enter correct Artist and Song title")
                if len(lyrics) > 2048:
                     lyrics = lyrics[:2048]
                emb = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}" , description = f"{lyrics}",color = 0xa3a3ff)
                await ctx.send(embed=emb)
        await session.close()```
````

Comment: When I encounter an error, here's what goes through my mind: What could throw a KeyError? Accessing a dictionary key that doesn't exist. What key am I supposedly accessing? The error tells me -- `"lyrics"`. Where do I try to access a `'lyrics'` key in a dictionary? Right here: `lyrics = data['lyrics']`. What could it mean if the `data` dict doesn't have a `'lyrics'` key? How would I handle this? Hint: I already have, I just need to add this other condition to that `if` statement!

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you.

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply! I'll be right at it to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

If `lyrics` not in your `json` object then python will raise `KeyError`. If you want to avoid from this, you can use `get` method.

```
data = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}

value1 = data["key1"] #no error
value2 = data.get("key2") #no error
value3 = data["key3"] #this will raise KeyError because key3 not in data
value3 = data.get("key3") #this will not raise any error and return default value
value3 = data.get("key3", "No lyrics could be found.") #we passed the default value so this will return
         #"No lyrics could be found" if key3 is not exist in json
```