# lyrics command in discord.py keyerror

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I recently made a lyrics command and its working! The only problem is that when I wrote gibberish it sent the error "An error occurred: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'lyrics'" for which I added an except KeyError error handler but it didn't work, any idea why?

```py
@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self, ctx,*, title):
     url = f"https://some-random-api.ml/lyrics?title={title}"
     response = requests.get(url)
     json_data = json.loads(response.content)
     lyrics = json_data['lyrics']
     try:
       if len(lyrics) > 2048:
          em = discord.Embed(title=title,description = f"I wasn't able to send the lyrics for that song since it exceeds 2000 characters. However, here's the file for the lyrics!",color=0xa3a3ff)
          await ctx.send(embed=em)
          file = open("lyrics.txt", "w")
          file.write(lyrics)
          file.close() 
          return await ctx.send(file=discord.File("lyrics.txt"))
       else:
          em = discord.Embed(title=title,description=lyrics,color=0xa3a3ff)
          await ctx.send(embed=em)
     except KeyError:
       em = discord.Embed(title="Aw Snap!",description="I wasn't able to find the lyrics of that song.",color = 0xa3a3ff)
       em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830818408550629407/839555682436251698/aw_snap_large.png')
       await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67404308/lyrics-command-in-discord-py/67404858#67404858 Take a look if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try-except block is after the line causing the error.

```py
# ...
lyrics = json_data['lyrics'] # Erroneous line
try:
    # ...
```

If you wish the exception to occur and get caught, as is the pythonic way, you can move the `lyrics` declaration line into the try block.

Alternatively you can use get() to safely get the value and replace the try-except block with an if-else:

```py
# ...
lyrics = json_data.get('lyrics')
if lyrics:
    # Show lyrics
    if len(lyrics) > 2048:
        em = discord.Embed(title=title,description = f"I wasn't able to send the lyrics for that song since it exceeds 2000 characters. However, here's the file for the lyrics!",color=0xa3a3ff)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
        # ...
else:
    # Show message
    em = discord.Embed(title="Aw Snap!",description="I wasn't able to find the lyrics of that song.",color = 0xa3a3ff)
    em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830818408550629407/839555682436251698/aw_snap_large.png')
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: after trying out the "json_data.get('lyrics')" code, it worked but now Im getting another error when I write gibberish : 
An error occurred: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() @ankurbohra04

Comment: I believe you haven't put the content of the try: branch inside the if lyrics: branch, `len(lyrics)` should only be called if lyrics does exist, hence it must be placed inside the if lyrics: branch

Comment: I did, and it works but the error handler doesn't

Comment: I see, this is supposed to replace the error handler, not aid it. json_data.get() will not error even if lyrics are not found, hence no error handling is required. I have edited my answer to indicate the branches.

Comment: if not len(lyrics):
       em = discord.Embed(title="Aw Snap!",description="I wasn't able to find the lyrics of that song.",color = 0xa3a3ff)
       em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830818408550629407/839555682436251698/aw_snap_large.png')
       await ctx.send(embed=em)

Comment: This is the code after the if len(lyrics) > 2048: and else statement

Comment: No that will not work, I have not provided you working complete code. The comments saying ... were to imply that the appropriate code has to be added there. I believe there's a bit of a misunderstanding here, have you understood how the try-except block has been translated into the if-else block?

Comment: Bro tysm it works now but the only prob is of the if len(lyrics) > 2048 statement, if the lyrics is 2000+ characters then it returns a bad request rather than sending it in a text file like it was before

Comment: That seems out of scope for this question, create a different question with the required information.

Comment: Okay I've created a new questions, please do check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414005/if-statement-not-working-in-lyrics-command

Answer (score 0):

The error happens on this line: `lyrics = json_data['lyrics']`.  You should put the `try-except` around it. Or a blocking `if` statement which handles missing lyrics:

```
lyrics = json_data.get('lyrics', None)
if not lyrics:
    em = discord.Embed(title="Aw Snap!",description="I wasn't able to find the lyrics of that song.",color = 0xa3a3ff) 
    em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830818408550629407/839555682436251698/aw_snap_large.png')
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
    return
...
```

Comment: Are you still getting the KeyError?

Comment: nah im getting a new error : "An error occurred: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

Comment: I've changed the code to a if else if statement now btw