# if statement not working in lyrics command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i recently made a lyrics command, it works but it returns the error : An error occurred: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.description: Must be 2048 or fewer in length. returns this error when the lyrics is more than 2048 characters. i've already made a way for it to send a txt file instead of the error above but it isn't working. Here's the code :

```py
@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self, ctx,*, title):
     url = f"https://some-random-api.ml/lyrics?title={title}"
     response = requests.get(url)
     json_data = json.loads(response.content)
     lyrics = json_data.get('lyrics')
     lyrics = json_data.get('lyrics')
     if lyrics: 
       em = discord.Embed(title=title,description=lyrics,color=0xa3a3ff)
       return await ctx.send(embed=em)
       if len(lyrics) > 2048:
         em = discord.Embed(title=title,description = f"I wasn't able to send the lyrics for that song since it exceeds 2000 characters. However, here's the file for the lyrics!",color=0xa3a3ff)
         await ctx.send(embed=em)
         file = open("lyrics.txt", "w")
         file.write(lyrics)
         file.close() 
         return await ctx.send(file=discord.File("lyrics.txt"))
     else:
        em = discord.Embed(title="Aw Snap!",description="I wasn't able to find the lyrics of that song.",color = 0xa3a3ff)
        em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830818408550629407/839555682436251698/aw_snap_large.png')
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: The size check is *after* using `discord.Embed()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the embed after you've checked the lyrics' length, i.e **if** the length of the lyrics is > 2048 make the file and corresponding embed **else** make the normal embed. We can translate this naturally into code:

```py
    # ...
    if lyrics:
        if len(lyrics) > 2048:
            # Lyrics are too large to send through embed
            em = discord.Embed(title=title,description = f"I wasn't able to send the lyrics for that song since it exceeds 2000 characters. However, here's the file for the lyrics!",color=0xa3a3ff)
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
            file = open("lyrics.txt", "w")
            file.write(lyrics)
            file.close() 
            return await ctx.send(file=discord.File("lyrics.txt"))
        else:
            # Lyrics can directly be sent through embed
            em = discord.Embed(title=title,description=lyrics,color=0xa3a3ff)
            return await ctx.send(embed=em)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is coming after sending message. Also you can send txt file without saving it.

```
import io

@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self, ctx,*, title):
    url = f"https://some-random-api.ml/lyrics?title={title}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    data = data.get('lyrics')
    title = data.get("title")
    author = data.get("author")
    lyrics = data.get("lyrics")
    if lyrics:
        if len(lyrics) < 2000:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f"{title} - {author}",
                description = lyrics,
                color = 0xA3A3FF
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        else:
            s = io.StringIO(lyrics)
            file = discord.File(s, f"{title} - {author}.txt")
            await ctx.send(file=file)

    else:
        await ctx.send("No lyrics could be found.")
```

Comment: Works! although I already got the answer :p